# Unix reading from line

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file

```
 80.162.213.195:193.219. 52.163:193.219. 62.126:   82   76:          1:         46
193.219. 54. 75: 66.163.173.201: 62. 40.103.217:   76   82:          2:        100
193.219.160.130:192.117. 97.153: 62. 40.103.217:    3   82:          2:         80
193.219. 54. 73:194. 67. 23.251: 62. 40.103.217:   76   82:          6:        685
193.219.178.146:195. 22.174.130:193.219. 62.126:    4   76:        920:      38968
 63.240. 86. 34:193.219.163. 65:193.219. 61.247:   82    3:         18:      19326
193.219.140.  1:216.239. 51.101: 62. 40.103.217:   76   82:          2:         80
193.219. 76. 39:195. 14.178.189:193.219. 62.126:    4   76:          1:        397
193.219.174.174:217.230.136.  5: 62. 40.103.217:    0   82:          2:         96
193.219.160.134:208.172. 16.132: 62. 40.103.217:    3   82:         12:        516
193.219.163.246:213.226.132. 46:193.219. 62.126:    3   76:          1:         40
193.219. 61.  3:216. 21.234. 71: 62. 40.103.217:    3   82:          4:        300
212.122. 64.  6:193.219.191. 98:193.219. 61.247:   76    3:          7:        974
193.219. 61.  9:212. 59.  0.233:193.219. 62.126:    3   76:         14:       1369
```

and the `:` symbol here is like a separator. I need to read the two last numbers on each line. Is it possible to do that using the `awk` command? If not, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the awk `-F` option to set the separator to `:`, and print the final two fields:

```
awk -F: '{printf "%d %d\n", $(NF-1), $NF}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
awk '{ gsub(/:$/, "", $(NF - 1)); print $(NF - 1), "\t", $NF }'
```

Here `$NF` is a last column and `$(NF - 1)` is a column prior to the last. Here `gsub(/:$/, "", $(NF - 1));` trims away `:`.

Sample output for your file

```
$ cat test | awk '{ gsub(/:$/, "", $(NF - 1)); print $(NF - 1), "\t", $NF }'
1    46
2    100
2    80
6    685
920      38968
18   19326
2    80
1    397
2    96
12   516
1    40
4    300
7    974
14   1369
```

Comment: Using `gsub` seems a bit complex when you could use `-F:` instead, but I like that you've used `$(NF-1)` and `$NF`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your expected output it's a guess but this may be what you want:

```
cut -d: -f5- file
```